# Format of value for 'data' parameter of getIccAuthentication() of TelephonyManager class

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Can somebody familiar with the method getIccAuthentication() of class TelephonyManager of Android clarify the format of value to be passed to its 3rd parameter? The method signature as per Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getIccAuthentication(int, int, java.lang.String))
is  as following:

```
String getIccAuthentication (int appType, 
                int authType, 
                String data)
```

The third argument is supposed to be authentication challenge data received by client and as I understand it is *nonce*. Lower level calls used by the method also use name 'nonce' as parameter name. However, the documentation   refers to standard 3GPP TS 31.102 7.1.2 for more details. As per the document, argument value for the parameter 'data' has to be formatted as per section 7.1.2.3 or 7.1.2.4 in case of GBA bootstrapping.  This format is not simple nonce but a combination of a command, extracted RAND and AUTN values from nonce with lengths. So, my question is whether one need to pass just nonce received from servers  as the value for the third parameter or format the data as per 7.1.2.3/7.1.2.4 sections?

Comment: Did u get any solution to this ?? @mvsagar

Comment: This is pretty long ago required for a project and stopped working on it since then. I do not remember if I found a solution but if you really need it I can spend some time on a weekend and dig the source code to find it!

Comment: @mvsagar If possible can you share the code for the 3rd param.

Comment: @mvsagar good to hear from u. got it working. thanks a lot :)